# Interview: what happens in memory when i initialize String str=”abc”; String str1=”abc”; String str=”xyz”

Tags: java, string, memory

Recently i attended an interview there they asked this question which i was unable to answer.

what happens in memory when i initialize

```
String str = "abc"; 
String str1 = "abc"; 
String str = "xyz";
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile?

Comment: unless it was asked this way, please correct the type of quotes `""`

Comment: Was this really an interview question? I never was asked in interviews for such knowledge. And that's good. I believe, knowledge about OOP, design patterns, best practices, whatever, are much more valuable than to know String pooling (although I also think, that good Java programmers should know such internals).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes even i was shocked. The guy was asking only about strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think it as Like this,

1. When first Variable `Str` is initialized with **"abc"** then **Literal** **"abc"** gets memory in **String Pool** so variable `Str` gets reference to this **"abc"**.

   `Str` --------------------------------> `abc`
2. On Second Step, in similar fashion another variable reference to same literal in **String Pool** .

   `Str` --------------------------------> `abc` <------------------------------- `Str1`
3. In final Step , if considered `String Str` then an `Error` will occur  like this:-

   `variable Str is already defined`

   So instead i will take `Str = "xyz"` on doing this a `New` literal will get memory in **String Pool** and `Str` previous reference will be deleted and new reference will be assigned.

   `Str` -----------X-------------> `abc` <----------------------- `Str1`

   `Str` --------------------------> `xyz`
4. Finally we will get this and will have 2 **Literals** namely `abc` and `xyz` in **String Pool**

   `Str` --------------------------> `xyz`   and  `Str1` --------------------------> `abc`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the third variable should have a different name:

At compile time, the identical `"abc"` strings will both be pulled into the string pool, along with the `"xyz"`. So  you'll end up with two String variables pointing to the same instance of `"abc"` and one pointing to `"xyz"`.

Answer (score 0):

A string object will be created in String constant pool(SCP) with content

```
 "abc"
```

1.`str` refernce will be pointed to that object.

While creating second object jvm will check whether the same "abc" content available in SCP or not
in your case already available so

2 `str1` will be pointed to existing object

3.`String str="xyz"`  already `str` is pointing to `abc` content object again we are assigning to `xyz`

```
Code will not compile as you are using duplicate `str` variable
```